# Configure Android Activity full screen with white background color

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm pretty much new to Android application development. I want my first Activity to display in full screen with white background. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add following attribute to your Activity in Android Manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```